# Book about aggressive aliens invasion

Tags: story-identification

Just need a bit of help identifying this book. I contacted Amazon customer rep and they cannot access old kindle special offers as these are random generated based on what I've read.

**What is it?**  A book I saw on my kindle special offers that is no longer there. It was there 2 weeks ago, but when I got home it synced and replaced it with new ones.

**Unique Details** The unique details I remember from the book description were that these were aggressive aliens. Also they hop from planet to planet until they deplete their resources. Last detail I remember was that planet earth was next. I can't remember if Earth somehow knew they were coming i.e.

**When did you see it?** It was on my kindle special offers, probably a few weeks, about 2 weeks ago. I am bumping my head as to why I didn't write it down now. At the time I didn't have wifi, and kindle doesn't let you save special offers for future purchases.

**Setting** I don't remember if this was set in the future.

**Vague details** I can't remember for sure but I think the aliens came straight to do their job, killing every human they could kill no questions asked and no demands. And the rest were used as slaves for their depletion jobs. I think the name was one word, and the title caught my eye also. I know if I see it again with the book cover I'll remember.

**New Vague detail** Cover color was blue or purple. I know is vague but I am inclining more towards blue in my memory. I hope this helps for those that have perhaps read the book.

I don't think is "*Out of dark*".

Comment: This is very very broad, and is the plot theme of almost all alien invasion stories, can you add *any* more details at all? Specifically have a look at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267)to help jog your memory.

Comment: I'll add more information tomorrow. Jumping from planet to planet depleting resources is not found on most book descriptions. I looked at many alien invasion books.

Comment: @fredz0003. I would have to agree with Mooz.  This may be a bit tough without some more information to narrow it down. In addition to using the link Mooz povided, you might try the following google link search.  I set it look for Kindle Alien Invasion books in descending publication order.  Perhaps you can page down the listing and spot the title. In particular if you know the date.Good luck.  https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_st/162-3489295-0419765_date-desc-rank?rh=n%3A133140011%2Cn%3A!133141011%2Cn%3A154606011%2Cn%3A668010011%2Cn%3A158591011%2Cn%3A6809434011&qid=1489542610&sort=date-desc-rank

Comment: Have you tried setting your Kindle’s location to that of the country or location you visited, and seeing if the book shows up in the special offers then?

Comment: "And earth was next"? Do you mean that in the book, the aliens have not yet invaded earth, but we know they're coming? Is the book set in the present or near future?

Comment: @user14111 Sorry I don't remember the setting. However on the earth was next? It is unknown to me how did earth knew they were coming, or if this was just written by the author as a description detail to capture the reader. I've edited my post, but well it is now on hold.

Comment: @Adamant I spoke to amazon and according to them the location doesn't change the special offers, there is no setting to change the location anyways. It is based on what I've read and browsed. The current offers I see some got 4.5 stars while some do not have the star ratings. For now I will try to search to books published within the last year and at least 3 start ratings.

Comment: I have been looking through pages and pages of amazon books. It might be a lost cause. Is just giving me this headache the book name is in the back of my head too.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but could it be 'The Fold' by Peter Clines?

Comment: @Liesmith Definitely not "The Fold" thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys after searching like crazy, I thought I had written down or searched the books on the internet, but nothing I went thru my browsing history and notes. I only had wifi on my laptop and I couldn't use it on my kindle because it is MAC address based. Anyways I used advanced google search, and advanced search on kindle books. The best title I can come up based on the little I remember is "[Constitution](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25817087-constitution)". Only thing is depletion, deplete resources is not there. But oh well I hope Kindle keeps updating special offers maybe one of these days it will popup again. Now I have about a dozen or more interesting books I managed to gather in this searched, all saved on my amazon account :) Thanks for all the help, waste no more time on this thread!

> The year is 2650
>   75 years ago, an alien fleet attacked Earth.
>   Without warning. Without mercy.
>   We were not prepared.
>   Hundreds of millions perished. Dozens of cities burned.
>   We nearly lost everything.
>
> Then, the aliens abruptly left.
>
> We rebuilt. We armed ourselves. We swore: never again.
>   But the aliens never came back.
>
> Until now.
>
> With overwhelming force the aliens have returned, striking deep into our territory, sending Earth into a panic. Our new technology is useless. Our new ships burn like straw. All our careful preparations are wasted.
>
> Now, only one man, one crew, and the oldest starship in the fleet stand between the Earth and certain destruction:
>
> ISS CONSTITUTION

[image: Consitution Book cover]

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *"Invasion"*? It's the first novel of a 7 part series called "Alien Invasion" by Sean Platt and Johnny Truant. It's on Amazon and it looks like it was on sale on Kindle.

> First visible only as blips on a telescope image, the discovery of **objects approaching from Jupiter orbit** immediately sets humanity on edge. NASA doesn't even bother to deny the alien ships' existence. The popular Astral space app (broadcasting from the far side of the moon and accessible by anyone with internet) has already shown the populace what is coming. So the news has turned from evasion to triage, urging calm and offering the few facts they have:
>
> The objects are enormous, perfectly round spheres numbering in the dozens, maybe hundreds. They are on an approach vector for Earth. And they will arrive in six days.

[https://www.amazon.com/Invasion-Alien-1-Sean-Platt/dp/1629550434](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1629550434)

Reading the descriptions of this and the other novels, the part about hopping from planet to planet depleting resources doesn't match your recollection. In *Alien Invasion* the invaders actually colonize Earth. They don't try to wipe out all Humans.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I read the description and the cover, neither one rings a bell. Interesting book series as well so I will add that one to my wishlist too.

Answer (score 1):

It just *might* be one of the [Earthrise](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XKX33RD) books, possibly the fourth - *Earth Fire*. It was an Amazon special offer around a month ago, and it vaguely matches. From the blurb, however, you couldn't have guessed the slavery details you cite.

> They emerge from shadows. Hungry for flesh, they scurry forth. They
>   are the marauders, the galaxy's deadliest predators.
>
> And they crave Earth.

Comment: If there is one thing that I know was for sure in the description was that "Earth was next", also I am 75% that hoping from planet to planet was part of the description too. I hard read the Earthriser a few hours ago and that one didn't ring any bells either. Thanks anyways!